# Open source chat app for Facebook

Tags: android, open-source, chat, facebook

I am looking for an open-source Facebook chat app.

Absolute requirements:

- Open source
- Ability to disable GPS permanently (or no GPS feature)
- Show notifications for new messages
- Ability to search friends by typing name or part of it (not necessarily the start of name/surname), including offline friends

Very desirable:

- Reasonably low bandwidth
- Easy to stop (to save bandwidth when sleeping)
- Show connection mode of friends (Web, Mobile)
- Show "frequent friends" first, like on Web interface
- Intent to send pictures from camera to chat app conversation

I am aware that any XMPP app can cover a part of these requirements, but which app covers the most?

Comment: I don't know about the friends search bit, but [Conversations](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=conversations&fdid=eu.siacs.conversations) is a very nice XMPP client.

Comment: @Turion: Feel free to add it as an answer, thanks! :-)

Comment: https://crypto.cat/

Answer (score 1):

There are many XMPP clients with such features. One I tried with the Facebook chat is the well-known Pidgin.

I see Gajim can also use a certificate as well as sync contacts. Poezio can also use certificates, no idea about contacts sync.

However, [XMPP clients were dropped by Facebook](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/04/facebook-chat-api-empathy-pidgin-stop-working), it seems: right now Pidgin and Empathy can't be used. Does Facebook allow any chat app right now, or is this question superseded?

Comment: Pidgin does not satisfy this absolute requirement: "*Ability to search friends by typing name or part of it (not necessarily the start of name/surname), including offline friends*"

Comment: IIRC it worked last time I tried (I have 2.10.11-2.fc21 currently), but right now I seem to have connection issues with Facebook. Oh! http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/04/facebook-chat-api-empathy-pidgin-stop-working